# Need Help creating a Registration script with Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so i am trying to create a signup script i am using steps i found on Codecademy but for some reason it is not working.

[Rails Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQe6J.png)

Below is the "New" page for registration

```
<div class="login">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="form">

<h1>Sign up</h1>

    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => "First name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => "Last name" %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %>
  <%= f.submit "Create an account", class: "btn-submit" %>
<% end %>

</div>
```

Here is my Users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

and the user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

   has_secure_password

end
```

and finally my db:migrate file for my users

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Try running `rake db:migrate` just to make sure your database is up to date.

Comment: The error indicates that the first name field is missing from the users table. If you have already run this migration... did you go back and alter it at any time (eg to add in the first/last name)? Migrations can't be altered if they've already been run - running them again will result in no change (because your db already registers it as having been run).

Comment: Yes, before you can edit a migration you have to run `rake db:rollback`. So did you edit the migration without doing that?

Comment: That was it! i just had to roll back and migrate again. thank you guys!

Comment: Great, I put it in an answer, can you mark it as accepted so that the question is shown as answered?

Comment: @Noah Think you can help me with one more thing? if not i will create a new question

Comment: or @TarynEast ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079836/adding-a-ror-registration-script-into-a-bootstrap-modal

Comment: Always make a new question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you edit a migration you need to run `rake db:rollback` and then once you edit it you need to run `rake db:migrate`.