# Adding a RoR registration script into a bootstrap modal

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-modal

so i am trying to create a signup script within a Bootstrap Modal
but it fails out.

the same script works on a page of its won, just not sure why it doesnt work here.

is there something special about using bootstrap?

Here is the Error: [image: Rails Error]

Below is the Modal Contents

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="register-modal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Register</h4>
      </div>
       <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <%= f.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => "First name" %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <%= f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => "Last name" %>                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
               <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>
            </div>
          </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <%= f.submit "Create an account", class: "btn btn-primary btn-submit" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is my Users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

and the user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

   has_secure_password

end
```

and finally my db:migrate file for my users

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

One more bit of is my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'

  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: in your controller add INDEX method and copy what's inside your NEW the reason maybe is because @user is not defined in the index controller.

Comment: so like this?

  `class UsersController < ApplicationController

      def index
         @user = User.new
      end
    end`

Comment: yes. try it @Ezekiel

Comment: @bxorcloud still did not work, same error.

Comment: I modified the original post with my routes. is that the problem?

Comment: ahhh so the index is in te home controller. so you sould put that INDEX METHOD into your home Controller.

Comment: can also see it live, here [link](http://thefandomnetwork.ddns.net:3000/)

Comment: don't i need the user controller to register users though?

Comment: you still need it but right now for that error you need to put the index you type from user conroller to home controller to solve first this issue.

Comment: Okay, so that worked, but now the problem is my Index content is hidden until i open the Modal...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135006/discussion-between-ezekiel-hammond-and-bxorcloud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby you can reference a instance variable even if it has not been initialized:

```
irb(main):001:0> @foo
=> nil
```

Which is exactly what is happening here. If you want to use the same form  on a bunch of actions without worrying if the controller sets the `@user` instance variable you can just use the `||` (or)
 operator:

```
<%= form_for(@user || User.new) do |f| %>
   # ...
<% end %>
```